# Is it possible to proxy a npm repository from Artifactory to Nexus?

Tags: npm, artifactory, nexus

Is it possible to proxy a npm repository from Artifactory to Nexus?

I tried to proxy this repo:

https://repo.platform.here.com/artifactory/webapp/#/artifacts/browse/tree/General/maps-api-for-javascript

(Here is an example of a link to download the 1.39.0 version:
https://repo.platform.here.com/artifactory/api/npm/maps-api-for-javascript/-/@here/maps-api-for-javascript-1.39.0.tgz)

to my Nexus (with a npm proxy repo), but without success.

Can someone have an idea?

Comment: `... but without success` which is a synonym of `... it's not working` [is not an accurate description of the issue you're facing](https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/)

Answer (score 0):

To proxy an NPM package from Artifactory to Nexus, I would perform the following:

1. Set up a repository in Nexus to store the NPM packages. You can create a new hosted repository or a proxy repository depending on your needs.
2. Configure the npm registry settings in Nexus by setting the npm registry URL to the URL of the Nexus repository you just created.
3. In Artifactory, set up a remote repository to proxy the NPM packages from their original source.
4. Set up a virtual repository in Artifactory that includes the remote repository you just created and the local repository that stores your NPM packages.
5. Export the NPM packages from Artifactory and import them into Nexus using the following command:
   npmrc=$(mktemp); echo "registry = " >> $npmrc; npm login --registry= --scope=@ --auth-type=oauth --always-auth --registry= --config=$npmrc

Replace  with the URL of the Artifactory repository you set up to proxy the NPM packages, with the URL of the Nexus repository you created to store the NPM packages,  with the package scope (e.g., @my-scope), and  with the URL of the public NPM registry.

6. Use the following command to download and re-upload the NPM packages from Artifactory to Nexus:
   npm pack @ npm publish @.tgz --registry= --access=public

Replace  and  with the name and version of the NPM package you want to transfer.
Repeat this step for all NPM packages you want to transfer from Artifactory to Nexus.

Once all NPM packages have been transferred, you can switch your project's NPM registry to the Nexus registry URL, and your project should start using the NPM packages from the Nexus repository.